# Cannot add new Row to Datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I am trying to add two new Rows to a DataTable. My DataSource consist of a Database with one Table (FooTable) and one column (FooName).

See following code. Only the first Row "Mary" is added and displayed on my DataGrid, but not the second row "Jesus".  No exception occurs. Why doesn't it work and what is the correct way to add multiple rows dynamically to DataTable?

```
/* dg1 = DataGrid; ds = DataSet */
dg1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables;

/* dt = DataTable */
DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
newRow["FooName"] = "Mary";
dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

/* add another row to data table */
DataRow newRow2 = dt.NewRow();
newRow2["FooName"] = "Jesus";
dt.Rows.Add(newRow2);
```